# How could I put a references of Ajax Control Toolkit in a GAC

Tags: development, assembly-references

How Could i put a references to the Gac. I want to putting a dll file to the AjaxControl Toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure this video tutorial will gonna help you but make sure to do a IIS Reset after.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_QSoIMEzeU

Its quiet simple, all you need to do is, drag your dll into Assembly folder in Windows which is located mostly in drive where you installed Operating System.

Hope it helps :).

Comment: just posting a link on stackexchange isnt sufficent as links get deleted and so do vids after a sertin ammount of time or inactivity. As its somthing so basic you could atleast explain what is going on rather than post a link to a video!

Comment: But it's don't work me. After add to Assemblies the error shows again.

Comment: whats the error now

Answer (score 2):

Just drag and drop the ajaxcontroltoolkit into the assembly. You can add the ajaxcontrolltoolkit dll also to your project through references. Do an iisreset as you made an ammendment to the GAC(assembly).

Now your project (webpart or anything that is using the ajax dll) has reference to the ajax dll.

hope it helps :)